# FFMPEG Transcode so that I can view from iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, safari, ffmpeg, h.264, quicktime

I've been searching all day for a way to transcode files that are being uploaded to something that iPhone's can handle (in Safari) without any success. I've read that it's best to use `Quicktime` for iPhone with the `h.264 codec` but I am struggling to find either the correct dependencies or the correct syntax for this. I have already managed to convert to mp4 and webm .

Mp4:

```
'ffmpeg -i '.$input.' -strict experimental -s 1024x760 -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -mbd 2 -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp -2 '.$filepath.'/'.$filename.'.mp4'
```

Webm

```
'ffmpeg -i '.$input.' -b 600 -s 1024x760 -ab 128k -vcodec libvpx -ab 128k -acodec libvorbis '.$filepath.'/'.$filenamewithoutext.'.webm'
```

Anyone know how to get these videos available for Safari (on iPhone/Pad)?

Comment: Please show the actual, unscripted commands and the complete ffmpeg console outputs.

Comment: Well, the ones I listed are working. I am just struggling to find a way that is actually playable from an apple iPhone. I only pasted them to show how I got support for Computers and Android phones, but iPhone seems to be a pain in the ass to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are much more options which can be set for the input file as well for the output file.

However, I have found this german site : http://www.quadhead.de/videos-mit-ffmpeg-fur-das-iphone-konvertieren-und-streamen/ with this command :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -r 29.97 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x320 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -deblockalpha 0 -deblockbeta 0 -b 400k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -subq 4 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -acodec aac -ab 80k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict experimental -y "%~1".mp4
```

Yes, I'm german ;) that's the reason for my bad english. So feel free to correct my posts. But hey... I like ffmpeg too.

Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the official ffmpeg documentation on http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide, this is my suggestion to encode a video file to at least Apple Quicktime compatibility :

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart -profile:v normal -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -cutoff 15000 -b:a 128k OUTPUT.mp4
```

Have a nice day ;)

Comment: Been trying it in a few different variations, but it does not seem to work. Perhaps it matters which file I transcode from?